# How to access Entity type members in POCO class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, ria

I am pondering over my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960944/cannot-access-entityobject-type-via-ria-services) and was wondering whether a [POCO class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg602754%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) can have a member of Entity Object type that can be accessed from client via RIA service.

```
public class CompositeData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PKey { get; set; }
    public string CompositeName { get; set; } 
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    public Product CurrentProduct { get; set; }  //Product is an auto-generated EntityObject class

    public CompositeData()
    {
        PKey = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm - if your POCO class had a member that was of type EntityObject then it wouldn't be a POCO class anymore. The point of POCOs is to abstract away the references to enitity framework for things like testing. POCOs being 'plain old CLR objects' wouldn't be very plain with an EntityObject type in there.

You can use straight (geninue) POCO objects with RIA services though as this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133414/POCO-Entities-Through-RIA-Services) demonstrates.

Comment: But I need to pass custom class objects that has Entity objects as members. How would you advise to do that?

Comment: I don't think you're actually using POCO's if you have "auto generated EntityObjects".  When you use POCO's, it disables generation of EntityObjects, and you should use POCO's that map to those tables.